# how to do authentication in firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Usually we can do authentication from web using firebase (web) SDK, which is well described:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider(providerId);
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((value) => {
...
}
```

Now I am trying to implement authentication in Firebase cloud functions and the above does not work on server side (`firebase-admin` does not have `OAuthProvider`).

Take a specific example, I want a new user to click "Sign Up With Google" button which then will trigger a Cloud Function, inside which the user will be redirected to a consent screen and once the uses logged in, the token and refresh token will be stored. I guess here I need two cloud functions: one for redirect and the other one for the callback?

Is there any build in functionality from `firebase-admin` to help me achieve this or do I have to manually implement the auth flow?

Comment: The question is not clear to me.  What do you mean when you say "implement authentication in Firebase cloud functions"?  What exactly are you missing in your implementation where you need support from the Firebase Admin SDK?  Please edit the question to be more clear where you're stuck.

Comment: @derek do you want a cloud function to be triggered when a new user clicks on the "sign up with Google" button for the first time (thus creating a new account) / or every time they log in via that auth provider?

Comment: The `functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => { ... })` option is available ([auth events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), but as Doug said it's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited again. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @PatNeedham New user.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Firebase Auth SDKs are very different for client and server use, and it seems you might be mixing them up.

Comment: > a new user to click "Sign Up With Google" button which then will trigger a Cloud Function, inside which the user will be redirected to a consent screen
@derek That part confuses me - or at least the "user will be redirected " part does. Why does that need to happen inside a cloud function? If the OAuth authentication was successful, that can be handled from the client-side `auth.signInWithPopup(provider)` promise once it resolves.

Comment: @PatNeedham I guess what you said makes sense. We can do the authentication/authorization on front end.  My case is this: after the user authorize my app, I will store the token and refresh token for later use, which will be used in a cloud function. In this case,  how can we get the token or refresh token in a cloud function?